# Way to demo Program written in IDE to project partner?

Tags: java, eclipse, project-management, collaboration, tfsbuild

I have java code written in eclipse and I want to show some basic functionality to a partner who is both far away and isn't really versed in Java. Even if he were, I would still want the interaction to be more of a presentation.

Is there anything better than a screen sharing app for this? what do you guys do/use?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to demo a program?

Comment: Yes demo a program but from within the eclipse IDE

Comment: As I understand you want to demonstrate console application. Am i right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen sharing is pretty straight forward. I have used [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) myself for such things. Works very well, even across less than optimal connections.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of desktop sharing, like  [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[GoView](http://goview.com) is an option, if you want something that's more like a presentation and less like a screen-sharing session.

Answer (score 0):

For navigating between code It would be useful to use IntelliJ IDEA's internal messenger IDETalk (which uses jabber). You can easily share code links there - i.e. send 'Code pointers'.

Also If you want to see and make live changes - may be it would be good idea to work within shared Dropbox folder (Or similar cloud file hosting). For this workflow IDEA is preferred than Eclipse because it supports live file update (in Eclipse you need to press F5 each time).

HTH

Comment: The OP wrote explicitly that the partner "isn't really versed in Java" so navigating through code doesn't seem like an option.